# How to fit my design to all devices?

Tags: android

Hi I am developing a app in which alphabets are not fitting for every device. For HCL ME tablet my design won't fit. For samsung it is working. MY XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="2" android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter1" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"></TextView>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter2" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dip"></TextView>
            <TextView  android:id="@+id/letter3" android:gravity="center" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dip"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView android:id="@+id/imag"  
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType = "fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="center">
        </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/previous" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Previous" android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/practice" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Practice" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="onClick"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/home" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Home" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/spell" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Spell" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="Content"></Button>
            <Button android:id="@+id/next" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:text="Next" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:onClick="Content"></Button>


        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my java file is:

```
package com.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;

public class MyAcivity extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {

    private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
    private static int counter=-1;
    private String[] mBtn1 ={"C","D","E","F","G","H","IÄ","J","K","L","M","N","O","CA","CB"};
    private TextView txtLetter;
    private ImageView imgLetter;

    private int[] imgArr={R.drawable.w1,R.drawable.w2,R.drawable.w3,R.drawable.w4,R.drawable.w5,R.drawable.w6,R.drawable.w7,R.drawable.w8,R.drawable.w9,R.drawable.w10,R.drawable.w11,R.drawable.w12,
            R.drawable.w13,R.drawable.w14,R.drawable.w15};
    private TextView txtKannada;
    private String[] mBtn2 = {"CgÀ¸À","DªÉÄ","E°","F±À","GqÀ","Hl","IÄ¶","J¯É","Kr","LzÀÄ","M¯É","N¯É","OµÀzsÀ",
            "CAUÀr","CB"};
    private String[] mBtn3 = {"ARASA","AME","ILI","ISA","UDA","UTA","RUSHI","ELE","EDI","AIDU","oLE","OLE","AUSHADA",
            "ANGADI","AHA"};
    private TextView txtEnglish;

    private int[] mAudio = {R.raw.a,R.raw.b,R.raw.c,R.raw.d,R.raw.e,R.raw.f,R.raw.g,R.raw.h,R.raw.i,R.raw.j,
            R.raw.k,R.raw.l,R.raw.m,R.raw.n,R.raw.o};
    protected MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content);   

        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
        if(counter == -1)
            counter =getIntent().getExtras().getInt("POSITION");
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(), "fonts/brhknd.ttf");
        txtLetter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter1);
        txtKannada = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter2);
        txtEnglish = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.letter3);
        imgLetter = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imag);
        txtLetter.setTypeface(tf);      
        txtLetter.setText(mBtn1[counter]);
        txtLetter.setTextSize(350);

        txtKannada.setTypeface(tf);
        txtKannada.setText(mBtn2[counter]);
        txtKannada.setTextSize(100);

        txtEnglish.setText(mBtn3[counter]);
        txtEnglish.setTextSize(50);

        Button btnNext =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(counter<imgArr.length-1)
                    counter++;
                changeContent();
            }
        });

        Button mPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.spell);
        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(MySwara.this, mAudio[counter]);   
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        Button btnPrvs =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.previous);
        btnPrvs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(counter>0)
                    counter--;
                changeContent();
            }
        });

        Button btnPractice = (Button)findViewById(R.id.practice);
        btnPractice.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MySwara.this,DrawingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Button btnHome = (Button)findViewById(R.id.home);
        btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MySwara.this,mainClass.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void changeContent()
    {
        txtLetter.setText(mBtn1[counter]);
        txtKannada.setText(mBtn2[counter]);
        txtEnglish.setText(mBtn3[counter]);
        //imgLetter.setBackgroundResource(imgArr[counter]);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgArr[counter]);
        imgLetter.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
        this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        String str = "";
        switch (direction) {
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT : str = "Swipe Right";
                if(counter>0)
                    counter--;
                    changeContent();
                break;
            case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT :  str = "Swipe Left";
                if(counter<imgArr.length-1)
                    counter++;
                    changeContent();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

How i can fit to all devices. Can anyone help?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

create xml for each device separately. follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8253626/779408)

---

second way:

create a parent LinearLayout and pass it to the following method

```
public static boolean isTabletPC(Context context) {
    Display display = ((WindowManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    if (display.getWidth() >= 1200) {
        isTabletPC = true;
        return isTabletPC;
    } else {
        isTabletPC = false;
        return isTabletPC;
    }
}

public static void fixUiDeviceDependencies(
        Activity act, LinearLayout llParent) {
    if (Utilities.isTabletPC(act)) {
        Display display = ((WindowManager) act
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) llParent
                .getLayoutParams();
        params.width = display.getWidth() / 2;
        llParent.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

}
```

Comment: But i want to implement dynamically.Because i want to fit it for tablets as well as mobiles.How should i change the code??

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of possibilities:

1. use different xml files for different sizes of screen -> check here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
2. you may use `scrollview` -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html
3. or simply make your layout fit to the smallest screen size you like to support and then just have "a little" unused space on the larger screens.

It really depends on what you need. Probably the most compatible and advanced solution would be 1.

BUT be aware of the fact that EVERY change on the screen layout has to be duplicated for each xml file following this route!

Comment: ps as you are new to SO, just a side comment ... once you accepted an answer don't forget to check it as accepted. This way you will keep getting attention to your questions high